# What's the best web application security program to learn XSS?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

I am learning web application security testing; specifically XSS. With so many web app programs, I wonder which is easiest to setup/configure, which is easiest to learn XSS, and which application the InfoSec community prefers? Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, product recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

OWASP's security shepherd is really good for learning, and you can configure it to only show challenges for specific types of vulnerabilities if XSS is all you're focusing on right now. You can download a VM [here](https://github.com/OWASP/SecurityShepherd/releases/tag/v3.0) and get it up and running in less than 10 minutes. If you're looking for less structure, there's BeeBox, which has pages where you can play around with vulnerabilities at different difficulty levels. That can be downloaded [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bwapp/files/bee-box/).

Answer (score 1):

[Damn Vulnerable Web Application](https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA) is a good place to start exploiting common vulnerabilities in a controlled environment. You can play with multiple vulnerabilities (which are part of [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project)) such as XSS, SQL injection, CSRF, command execution... It is fairly easy to install: the process is detailed in the README file.